# Regex capture group one

Tags: regex

I'm terrible at `regex` so forgive the basicness of this question. I currently have the following `regex` that will identify a UK postcode at the end of a string:

```
([a-zA-Z]{1,2}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-9][a-zA-Z])\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$)
```

And this works fine. However I'm now trying to do the opposite in that I want a `regex` that will identify everything else in the string, but NOT the postcode at the end of it. I've amended the regex as so:

```
((.+)[a-zA-Z]{1,2}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-9][a-zA-Z])\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$)
```

This successfully breaks it into capture groups, the string minus the postcode is identified (using a regex tester) as capture group 1. However, I don't know how to get it to select capture group 1 only?

Comment: Use a lookahead for anything you don't want to be included in the match.

Comment: What flavour code will you be using? Regex differs per language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead `(?=)` to select the string without the postcode.
Applied to your `regex` this will result in the following:

```
((.+)(?=[a-zA-Z]{1,2}([0-9]{1,2}|[0-9][a-zA-Z])\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}$))
```

the positive lookahead will find an expression where another expression follows, so `A(?=B)` will find expression `A` where it is followed by expression `B`

[more about lookarounds on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)